# Nautilus File Names

Tags: 12.04, gnome, nautilus, icons

Upgraded to 12.04 with gnome 3, how do i get the file names to be shown under or beside folders and files.
I have Configuration Editor but i just can't find it! I must have done this in 11.10 but i'm getting old.
Please treat me as a novice.

Answer (score 1):

First, open any folder that you choose to. After you have the file manager open, you will want to go to the menu for the program, click `Edit` and then click `Preferences`. After this, open the tab labeled `Views`. Now, look under `Icon View Defaults` for the box labeled `Text beside icons`. Click this box, and now all of the text for files and folders will be beside the icon.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, tried that and its no go, so i guess something must be wrong with Gnome or the config files.

Answer (score 0):

File names are shown under folders and files in Nautilus.  Something went wrong with your upgrade - probably due to gnome and old stuff in your config files.

Open up Terminal.

You can try some or all of:

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop^`

The caret is important.

`sudo apt-get install -f`

`sudo apt-get clean`

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

But before you do anything, make sure you have the means to restore all data and you also are able to re-install everything on your hard drive including any other operating systems you have.  A version upgrade can go horribly wrong.